# IE11 extension in AppData\Local folder

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, internet-explorer-11

I have working IE extension that I want to update for IE11 enchanced protected mode.

I have made both steps according to 
http://www.askyb.com/bho/step-by-step-guide-to-making-you-bho-epm-compatible-with-ie11-on-windows-8/

but my extension didn't work in folder other than "Program Files".

How should I specify rights for AppData\Local folder? Manifest? Guid in code? Registry Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments

---

Samarth Gupta
10 Jul 2013 11:42 PM

I'm trying to build a plugin for IE. I've completed it for both 32-bit and 64-bit and it's working on IE9 (both 32 and 64 bit). But when I use it on IE10 with EPM on, it's not loading. I've used "DEFINE_GUID(CATID_AppContainerCompatible, 0x59fb2056,0xd625,0x48d0,0xa9,0x44,0x1a,0x85,0xb5,0xab,0x26,0x40);"

in my plugin to register it to CATID_AppContainerCompatible, but it's still not loading.. Am I doing something wrong?

EricLaw: You need to store the .DLLs in an AppContainer-readable folder like the Program Files folder.

---

There is no any description for "AppContainer-readable folder", but I suppose that it is short list like ["program files", "program files(x86)", "windows" "windows\system32"]